# twilio api - HTTP Request Split in Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

How would I 'Split Based On' parsed JSON values from a HTTP Request ?
I know it's in the format 'widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed.[parsed variable name]', but there is no way I can get to enter this in the Split condition.
I know that they are being returned because I can add them to a SMS Message Body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's not obvious, and we're looking at redesigning to help with this, but if you start typing in the "Split Based On" widget's drop down box you can enter the format of the variable you want.

[image]

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.